# How can I fill the white color image to fill within that border in a shape of a glass?

Tags: unity

[image]

I'm using this in 2D canvas. Because I'm doing a health bar and it suppose to fill from the bottom to up but I don't know where to start from here.

Comment: Have you searched for [tutorials about implementing this effect](http://10minbasics.com/unity-image-fill-amount-health-bar/)? What did you try based on your research so far?

Comment: The link that @DMGregory posted is not available anymore, here's a link to a copy of the website on Internet Archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20190727002930/http://10minbasics.com/unity-image-fill-amount-health-bar/

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways on how you can do it. One way I could think of would be along the lines of:

1. First prepare your glass. The outer part of your image should be transparent. The inner part of your glass should be a seperate image.
2. Place them back on your canvas, you should see now just the glass with a white content.
3. You can assign a color for the inner glass.
4. The trick for filling your health (vertically I assume) is via the scale of the inner part. You need to change the anchor and pivot to bottom/ center (shift + lk in the rect transform) [image]

Example code could look like this

```
transform.localScale = new Vector3(1f, currentHitpoints / maxHitpoints, 1f);
```

Every time you have a change in your currentHitpoints, you would update the localScale of your inner glass. If you can have more HP than maxHp (some temporary or other mechanics) you need to clamp the value to 1f else it will overflow.

Comment: Why not use Image Type = ImageType.Filled and set its fillAmount? Scaling it will distort its shape.

Comment: Of course you are right. In case of OP's image the distorion made it look more natural (a slight hill like sand falling in a water glas). I will update the answer to include the fillAmount version as well.